# Mediaplayer works on Verizon 3g, but not Sprint

Tags: android

I have a simple app that connects to a shout cast stream.  It works fine on wifi.  It also works fine on Verizon 3g/4g but will not connect on Sprint 3g.  I have an onError listener and it shows error 1 and 503 for the extra tag.  Any ideas?  I get the same result on a Samsung Epic 4g and Epic 4g touch.

Comment: I've found the media player from device to device can be somewhat finicky. Especially so when you are streaming instead of playing something local.

Comment: After hours of searching and trial/error I found the problem to be with Sprint and the proxy server they use.  They are blocking the ports that I am trying to connect to.  So I deleted the proxy server settings in my phone and shazaam, it plays just fine now.  So the next step is to try and figure out how to do this in my code so that it will work for all Sprint users.